# trying to add seperator in alphabetically sorted list wen first letter will change

Tags: php, html, css

I sorted a list alphabetically and data from database mysql.To read the data i am using foreach loop.Now,I want when first letter (a->b->c) will change a seperator will be add after 'A' character list and so on.

Code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages order by name ASC"); 
foreach($result as $val){ 
   echo $val['name']."<br>"; echo "<hr></hr>"; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My code is :    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages order by name ASC");
foreach($result as $val){
echo $val['name']."<br>";
echo "<hr></hr>";
}

Comment: Edit the question to include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$first = '';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages order by name ASC"); 
foreach($result as $val){

    $first = substr($val['name'], 0, 1);

    if ($first != $prev){
        echo '<h1>'.$first.'</h1>';
    }

    echo $val['name']."<br>";

    $prev = $first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages order by name ASC"); 

$lastChar = "?"; //initialization

foreach($result as $val){ 
   if($lastChar != $val['name'][0]){    
     echo $val['name'][0].'<BR>';       //separator
   }
   echo $val['name']."<br>"; echo "<hr></hr>";
   $lastChar = $val['name'][0];         //update
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested code) :

```
$firstLetter = 'A';
foreach( $result as $val ) { 
  $ch = substr( $val['name'],1,1);
  if( $ch != $firstLetter ) {
    echo "<hr>";
    $firstLetter = $ch;
  }
  echo $val['name']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: This will retrieve the second letter, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$char = 'a';
foreach($result as $val) {
  $newChar = substr($val['name'],0,1);
  if ($newChar != $char) {
    $char = $newChar;
    echo "seperator for new character";
  }
  //do your other stuff
}
```

Is this what you were wanting to do?